# TypeScript relative module names resolution

Tags: module, typescript

I use TypeScript 1.8 and have the following file structure:

```
src
  reducers
    index.ts
    someReducer.ts
  app.tsx
```

**reducers/index.ts**

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import someReducer from "./someReducer";

const appReducer = combineReducers({
    someReducer
});

export default appReducer;
```

In **app.tsx** I am trying to import it like this:

```
import appReducer from "./reducers";
```

However, I get an error:

> Cannot file module './reducers'

I checked the [Modules Resolution](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) article, which says that TypeScript will look into `index.ts` in the folder, but apparently it does not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

index.ts will only be discovered and used if you are using `--moduleResolution node`, and it will only work at runtime if you are in Node.js or using a module loader that implements the same semantics as Node.js. (In other words, you are really better off explicitly specifying the file, instead of relying on Node.js-specific semantics.)

Comment: How does it correspond with ES6 compatibility since this is the standard syntax there?

Comment: I added `"moduleResolution": "node",` t my `tsconfig.json` and it helped, thanks.

Comment: ES6 does not define how module IDs are resolved. It only defines the module format. There is not currently any standard regarding how to actually resolve modules (the closest thing to an common interoperable standard is AMD; there is a WHATWG committee working on this separately).